# Why does ConnectableFlux.connect() block?

Tags: spring-reactor

I'm new to Spring Reactor. I've been trying to understand how the **ConnectableFlux** class works. I've read the docs and seen examples posted online but am stuck on an issue.

Can someone tell me why the **connect()** method is blocking? I don't see anything in the documentation that says it should block..especially since it returns a Disposable for later use.
Given my example code below, I never get past the connect() method.

I'm trying to basically simulate the old style Listener interface paradigm I've used many times in the past. I want to learn how to recreate a ***Service class & Listener*** architecture using Reactive streams. Where I have a simple **Service** class and it has a method called "*addUpdateListener(Listener l)*" and then when my service class "*doStuff()*" method it triggers some events to be passed to any listeners.

I should say that I will be writing an API for others to use, so when I say Service class I don't mean the @Service in Spring terms. It will be a plain java singleton class.

I'm just using Spring Reactor for the Reactive Streams. I was also looking at RxJava.. but wanted to see if Spring Reactor Core would work.

I was starting with a test class below just to understand the library syntax and then got stuck on the blocking issue.

I think what I'm looking for is described here: [Multiple Subscribers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux)

**UPDATE**: Running my code through a debugger, the code inside ConnectableFlux connect method, never returns. It hangs on the internal connect method and never returns from that method.

```
reactor.core.publisher.ConnectableFlux

public final Disposable connect() {
        Disposable[] out = new Disposable[]{null};
        this.connect((r) -> {
            out[0] = r;
        });
        return out[0];
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Here is my maven pom as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringReactorTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
                <version>Bismuth-RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.Disposable;
import reactor.core.publisher.ConnectableFlux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

/**
 * Testing ConnectableFlux
 */
public class Main {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main m = new Main();

        // Get the connectable
        ConnectableFlux<Object> flux = m.fluxPrintTime();

        // Subscribe some listeners
        // Tried using a new thread for the subscribers, but the connect call still blocks
        LOG.info("Subscribing");
        Disposable disposable = flux.subscribe(e -> LOG.info("Fast 1 - {}", e));
        Disposable disposable2 = flux.subscribe(e -> LOG.info("Fast 2 - {}", e));

        LOG.info("Connecting...");
        Disposable connect = flux.connect();// WHY does this block??
        LOG.info("Connected..");

        // Sleep 5 seconds
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        // Cleanup - Remove listeners
        LOG.info("Disposing");
        connect.dispose();
        disposable.dispose();
        disposable2.dispose();
        LOG.info("Disposed called");
    }

    // Just create a test flux
    public ConnectableFlux<Object> fluxPrintTime() {
        return Flux.create(fluxSink -> {
            while (true) {
                fluxSink.next(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }).doOnSubscribe(ignore -> LOG.info("Connecting to source"))
                .sample(ofSeconds(2))
                .publish();
    }
}
```

Running the above code gives the following output.. it just prints the time in milliseconds until I Ctrl-C the process..

```
09:36:21.463 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
09:36:21.478 [main] INFO Main - Subscribing
09:36:21.481 [main] INFO Main - Connecting...
09:36:21.490 [main] INFO Main - Connecting to source
09:36:23.492 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 1 - 1589808983492
09:36:23.493 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 2 - 1589808983492
09:36:25.493 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 1 - 1589808985493
09:36:25.493 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 2 - 1589808985493
09:36:27.490 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 1 - 1589808987490
09:36:27.490 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 2 - 1589808987490
09:36:29.493 [parallel-1] INFO Main - Fast 1 - 1589808989493
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received an answer from the Spring Reactor team and I'm just posting it here in case anyone else runs into this...

> The crux of the issue is that you're entering an infinite loop in
>   Flux.create. The moment the flux gets subscribed, it will enter the
>   loop and never exit it, producing data as fast as the CPU can. With
>   Flux.create you should at least have a call to sink.complete() at some
>   point.
>
> I suggest to experiment with eg. Flux.interval as a source for your
>   regular ticks, it will get rid of that extraneous complexity of
>   Flux.create, which puts you in charge of lower level concepts of
>   Reactive Streams (the onNext/onComplete/onError signals, that you'll
>   need to learn about, but maybe not just right now  ).
>
> As a side note, I would take into consideration that emulating a
>   listener-based API with Reactor (or RxJava) is not doing justice to
>   what reactive programming can do. It is a constrained use case that
>   will probably drive your focus and expectations away from the real
>   benefits of reactive programming
>
> From a higher perspective:
>
> The broad idea of ConnectableFlux#connect() is that you have a
>   "transient" source that you want to share between multiple
>   subscribers, but it gets triggered the moment someone subscribes to
>   it. So in order not to miss any event, you turn the source into a
>   ConnectableFlux, perform some set up (subscribe several subscribers)
>   and manually trigger the source (by calling connect()). It is not
>   blocking, and returns a Disposable` that represents the upstream
>   connection (in case you also want to manually cancel/dispose the whole
>   subscription).
>
> PS: Bismuth is now clearly outdated, prefer using the latest
>   Dysprosium release train